# How to spread Time value with Date pair using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to figure out how to spread the `time` value in the `date` value. My `Date` value looks like this:

```
date_list = ['2017-01-07', 
             '2017-01-08', 
             '2017-01-04', 
             '2017-01-05', 
             '2017-01-03', 
             '2017-01-04'
             .... ]
```

Here, as you can see the date are in somewhat pair format in order. For Example:

`'2017-01-07'` and `'2017-01-08'` or `'2017-01-04'` and `'2017-01-05'` etcs...

Basically, every two `date` pair value are one day apart.

I also have a time value:

```
time_list = [
     datetime.time(23, 0), 
     datetime.time(0, 0), 
     datetime.time(1, 0), 
     .... ]
```

What I am looking to do is to spread the time from `23` to `1` or basically form `11 PM` to `1 AM` with the two pair date `'2017-01-07'` and `'2017-01-08'` or `'2017-01-04'` and `'2017-01-05'` etcs... by preserving the original order of `date_list` with corresponding `time_list`

So the new `df` will look like this:

```
DateTimeList
2017-01-07 23:00:00
2017-01-08 00:00:00
2017-01-08 01:00:00
2017-01-04 23:00:00
2017-01-05 00:00:00
2017-01-05 01:00:00
2017-01-03 23:00:00
2017-01-04 00:00:00
2017-01-04 01:00:00
```

**What did I do?**

I put the time in between using:

`time = df.between_time('23:00:00','01:00:00')`

and then `time[time.index.normalize().isin(date_list)]`

however, this does not work because it does not spread the `time_list` after midnight on two date pair. It spreads the entire time from `22` to `01` on a single day. It also sorts the data.

But what I want is to spread the time value into two date pair by preserving the original order of `date_list` with corresponding `time_list`. Can you please help solve it?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `datetime.datetime.combine()` with some modulo logic?

```
import datetime

def combine_pairs(date_list, time_list):
    for i, x in enumerate(date_list):
        dt = datetime.date.fromisoformat(x)
        if not i % 2:
            yield datetime.datetime.combine(dt, time_list[0])
        else:
            yield datetime.datetime.combine(dt, time_list[1])
            yield datetime.datetime.combine(dt, time_list[2])
```

Demo:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> date_list = ['2017-01-07', 
...              '2017-01-08', 
...              '2017-01-04', 
...              '2017-01-05', 
...              '2017-01-03', 
...              '2017-01-04',]
>>> time_list = [
...      datetime.time(23, 0), 
...      datetime.time(0, 0), 
...      datetime.time(1, 0),]

>>> pprint(list(combine_pairs(date_list, time_list)))
[datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 7, 23, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 8, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 8, 1, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 4, 23, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 5, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 5, 1, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 3, 23, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 4, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 4, 1, 0)]
```